# Display data with the same id from a database

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, loops

I have a table called workdetails. I have a foreign key called personid to identify all the work details belonging to the same person. The qualificationdetails table consist of the following Fields:

- Qualificationid (Pri, INT, Auto_increment)
- QualificationType (Varchar)
- QualificationName (VarChar)
- InstitutionName (VarChar)
- CompletionYear (VarChar)
- Personid (Foreign Key, INT)

When the user completes a form, s/he will submit as many qualifications as they wish.  Now I would like to Retrieve this data and display it on a web page.  The following is the php code at the top of the page:

```
<?php
//Start the session
session_start();
//Connect to the database
require 'scripts/connect.php';
//Get the Person id
$persid = $_GET['Personid'];
//Select Applicant information from the tables
$Personid_query ="SELECT * FROM person where Personid=$persid";
$Qualification_query ="SELECT *FROM qualifications where Personid=$persid";

//Submit the selected information into the database
$Personid = mysql_query($Personid_query) or die(mysql_error);

$Qualificationid = mysql_query($Qualification_query) or die(mysql_error);

//Fetch the Applicant data
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($Personid);
$QDrow = mysql_fetch_assoc($Qualificationid);
//I need to have another look at this one as well
```

?>

The following code is within the html tags

**Qualification Name:**

```
                                <hr width ="50%" />
                              <table border="0">
                              <!-- Display Qualification details-->
                              <tr>
                              <td><strong>Institution Name:</strong></td>
                              <td><?php echo $QDrow['InstitutionName'];?><br/></td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                              <td><strong>Year Completed:</strong></td>
                              <td><?php echo $QDrow['CompletionYear'];?><br/></td>
                              </tr>
```

But the problem is that this above code only displays one Record, BUT I would like to display a Recoroder per person. for example

- Person 123
- Bachelor of Science
- Mathematics
- University of Germany
- 1999

---

- Person 1234
- Bachelor of Science
- Statistics
- University of London
- 2000.
  I really need assistance

Comment: You shouldn't really be using `mysql_*` functions. Switch to PDO.

Comment: How many rows does your above queries return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not to use JOIN

```
 $query ="SELECT * FROM person INNER JOIN qualifications ON   
person.Personid=qualifications.Personid where Personid=$persid";
```

Answer (score 0):

There a a number of qualification to a person, so you need to show all the qualifications

please try this

```
while($QDrow = mysql_fetch_array($Qualificationid)){
?>  
<tr>
   <td><strong>Institution Name:</strong></td>
   <td><?php echo $QDrow['InstitutionName'];?><br/></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
   <td><strong>Year Completed:</strong></td>
   <td><?php echo $QDrow['CompletionYear'];?><br/></td>
 </tr>    
<?php
}
```